# Scrapy spider Crawls 0 pages

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Thanks for having a look folks! Would really appreciate any help.

Doing [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCARQVJy_mk) tutorial on scrapy basics. My spider doesn't seem to return anything and hence, the csv file is empty. Below, I've pasted the spider code, and the message I receive in the terminal. Everything from the tutorial before the spider does work, ie running 'scrapy shell' and fetching snippets of info using CSS selectors. Note that those only work if I run the scrapy shell commands without '' around the URLs. Am on Windows and working in a virtual environment.

**Spider code**

```
import scrapy


class DronesspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dronesspider'
    allowed_domains = ['jessops.com/drones']
    start_urls = ['http://jessops.com/drones/']

    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.css('div.details-pricing')
        for product in products:
            item = {
            'name' : product.css('a::text').get(),
            'price' : product.css('p.price.larger::text').get()
            }
            yield item
        pass
```

**Return message in the terminal**

```
(venv) C:\Users\User\drones>scrapy crawl dronesspider -o drones.csv --set="ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False"
2023-03-24 10:04:07 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.8.0 started (bot: drones)
2023-03-24 10:04:07 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.2.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.2.0, parsel 1.7.0, w3lib 2.1.1, Twisted 22.10.0, Python 3.10.10 (tags/v3.10.10:aad5f6a, Feb  7 2023, 17:20:36) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 23.0.0 (OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023), cryptography 39.0.2, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
2023-03-24 10:04:07 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'drones',
 'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'drones.spiders',
 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION': '2.7',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': 'False',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['drones.spiders'],
 'TWISTED_REACTOR': 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor'}
2023-03-24 10:04:07 [asyncio] DEBUG: Using selector: SelectSelector
2023-03-24 10:04:07 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor
2023-03-24 10:04:07 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using asyncio event loop: asyncio.windows_events._WindowsSelectorEventLoop
2023-03-24 10:04:07 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: ec95e674fcfc2fd5
2023-03-24 10:04:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2023-03-24 10:04:08 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2023-03-24 10:04:08 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2023-03-24 10:04:08 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2023-03-24 10:04:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-03-24 10:04:08 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-03-24 10:04:08 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2023-03-24 10:04:09 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://jessops.com/> from <GET http://jessops.com/>
2023-03-24 10:04:09 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.jessops.com/> from <GET https://jessops.com/>
2023-03-24 10:04:09 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.jessops.com/> (referer: None)
2023-03-24 10:04:09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-03-24 10:04:09 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 637,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 24758,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.406225,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 24, 10, 4, 9, 336667),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 128442,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 6,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 24, 10, 4, 8, 930442)}
2023-03-24 10:04:09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Tried

1. Setting robotstxt_obey to false
2. Change the URLs
3. Change the ' to " to none in the URLs

None of the above changed anything to the output

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED.  Turned out I had 2 dronesspider.py files in my virtual environment folder. The one that was in the 'spiders' folder was the was that was running, and the 2nd was the one that I was working in. Deleted the 2nd and updated the 1st, and now its working.